# Update array in subdocument dynamically with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I need to update array field in subdocument and that works

```
User.findOne({ _id: id }, (err, user) => {
    if (!user) res.json({ error: "Email has not be found" });
    user.set({ "files.0.approved": isApproved });
    user.save((err, updatedUser) => {
      return res.send(updatedUser);
    });
 });
```

Nevertheless, I wonder how can I make it dynamic ? Since here I'm passing index manually - `files.0.approved`.

I tried using template strings, but it complains.

I also tried referring [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true), but could not figure it out.

If we assume that I can get index of array with `req.body.index`, how to prevent it from being hard-coded ?

Comment: How does it complaint while using template strings? Which error are you getting?

Comment: syntax error, "" expected instead of ``

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it this way.

```
 User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: id, "files._id": file_id },
    { $set: { "files.$.approved": isApproved } },
    (err, updatedUser) => {
      if (err) res.json({ error: "Something went wrong" });
      res.json({ message: "success" });
    }
  );
```

Apparently, you initially find the file you need to update and then mongoose has `$` operator that points to the index that has been found.